# systemd failure on binfmt services

Tags: linux, systemd, binfmt

Systemd has several failed services, and I don't know how to work it out:

```
# systemctl --failed
UNIT                              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    JOB DESCRIPTION
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount loaded failed failed     Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point
systemd-binfmt.service            loaded failed failed     Set Up Additional Binary Formats
```

More details:

```
# systemctl status systemd-binfmt.service
systemd-binfmt.service - Set Up Additional Binary Formats
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-binfmt.service; static)
      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue, 2012-11-27 07:42:11 CST; 36min ago
        Docs: man:systemd-binfmt.service(8)
              man:binfmt.d(5)
              https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt
     Process: 213 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-binfmt (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/systemd-binfmt.service

# systemctl status proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount; static)
      Active: failed (Result: resources)
       Where: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
        Docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a systemd unit fails, there are several things you can do. `journalctl -u [unit-name]` will show you all output generated by that unit. It can also be helpful to run `journalctl -f` while stopping and starting the service.

Many unit files that come with systemd have an associated man page. Try `man [unit-name]`. Additionally, the unit files can point to their own documentation. Both `systemd-bnfmt.service` man page and these two status outputs point to binfmt_misc.txt. That document has lots of information about registering interpreters for binary files. If looking through the journal doesn't yield any useful information, I'd look at the configuration in binfmt.d and manually register the interpreters and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, I think I get the problems now, `systemd-bnfmt (8)` helped